# how to handle response types with same status code but different meanings

Tags: python, django

I'm building an API and there are some cases where our frontend can make a request to the API sending in data from a form. The data is checked on the backend and a response status code of 200, 201, or 400 could be returned.

For example,
status code 200 can mean that the request was good from the frontend to the API, but there is a suggestion from the validated data. (user submitted data, backend validated and has a suggestion for the user). We could also return 200 where everything checks out and the user confirms once more that the validated data is looking good.
status code 400 can mean that the request was bad but due to a missing field, an empty field, or there wasn't enough data in the request such that the backend couldnt validate the form data.

My current approach is to send a response back with a message, type, and the status code.
For example, from the above:

```
{"message": "The username should be: xxxx", "type": 0}, 200
{"message": "Everything looks good!", "type": 1}, 200
{"message": "Missing field", "type": 2}, 400
{"message": "Submitted data couldn't be validated. Try again?", "type": 3}, 400
```

Then on the frontend, I am able to look at the type property and status code to decide what message or how to display to the user.

Does this sound like a good approach or can this be improved? Please share any thoughts or recommendations for best practices.

Answer (score 0):

Your backend should never send data that is suppose to guide the client on how to display a response or an error exception. The client alone is responsible for how messages, including error messages get displayed. The client UI can vary over time and even among devices.

If the user enters in some invalid data, you can perform the request and when you get back the response, you just display the error message in the appropriate location. Validation should be done on the client side and not allow the request to be sent when the input data is incorrect. Your backend can and should still validate the data being sent and return a 400 if it's incorrect, but the client app should just have a generic error handler for that. This really shouldn't happen though if you are validating on the client side.